# Owin WS-Federation. wsignoutcleanup1.0 not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, katana, ws-federation

After setting up WS-Federation in the new owin style, the wsignoutcleanup1.0 request seems that it's not working.

Setup:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
     AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
});
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
{
     MetadataAddress = "https://mysts.com/metadata",
     Wtrealm = "urn:myclient.com",
     SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies"
});
```

Now after being singned in - I try to perform a ws signout request **directly from browser** like this:

https://myclient.com/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0

#### Unfortunately no signing out is being performed. Why?

MSDN specs for wsignoutcleanup1.0: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236501.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this discussion: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/548376 it seems that it doesn't support yet.